# Изменение localhost

Tags: android, asp.net, retrofit

Есть сервер на `WebApi ASP.net`. Запускаю его на виртуальной машине. Вопрос такой, какой `url` указывать в `retrofit`, чтобы обратиться к серверу?

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны находиться в одной сети. Узнать IP адрес можно в консоли.

Если у вас Windows, откройте `cmd` и выполните `ipconfig`, найдите плату, которая подключена к вашей сети, вам нужен адрес поля `IPv4 Address`.

Если Linux, то там тоже самое, только команда `ifconfig`.